# How to remove few numbers from telephone number string - Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have few problems. I try to format telephone number in swift. Now i have only numbers.

```
var number = "(123) 456-789"

let clean = "".join(number.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet))
```

The question is. How to check indexes from 0...3 in this string. If there will be something like "0044" or in indexes 0...1 "44" then remove it.

Comment: What is it you're trying to get as result? It's not really clear to me. Do you want to reformat it or just numbers, check if there's a country code and remove it?

Comment: Now I can take only number.

 (123) 456-789 -> 123456789

But now I need to check first 2 or 4 numbers. If I have 0044 123456789 I need to remove this 0044.

Comment: I hope you have a very good reason to treat an international (UK in this case) phone number as a local phone number. I can almost guarantee that there will be people who have the same phone number if you ignore the country part. If you want to compare phone numbers you should internationalize all your phone numbers to the same format. e.g. 0044 12345678 becomes +44123456789 and US (123) 456-789 becomes +1123456789.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let number = "0044 123 456-7890"
let numberArray = map(number) { String($0) }
let numbersOnly = numberArray.filter { $0.toInt() != nil }
let numbers = "".join(numbersOnly.reverse()[0...9].reverse())
println(numbers) // Prints "1234567890"
```

This is just to give you a general example of how it can be done. I really don't like using fixed numbers for indexes. This should be safe if your phone numbers **always** have at least 10 numbers.

---

Updated the answer for Swift 4.
It's safe and crash friendly now!

```
let number = "0044 123 456-7890"
let numberArray = number.map { String ($0) }
var numbersOnly = numberArray.filter { Int($0) != nil }
let remove = numbersOnly.count > 3 ? numbersOnly[...3].joined() == "0044" : false
let result = numbersOnly[(remove ? 4 : 0)...]

print(result) // 1234567890
```

Comment: Updated the answer, can the downvote be removed now? :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I used the other answers and put together an extension for it (I included some range stuff from other answers on here)

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }

    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let start = startIndex.advancedBy(r.startIndex)
        let end = start.advancedBy(r.endIndex - r.startIndex)
        return self[Range(start ..< end)]
    }

    func phoneFormat() -> String {
        let numbers = self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^\\d]", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
        let tenchars = numbers.characters.suffix(10)
        if tenchars.count != 10 {
            return self
        }
        let last10 = String(tenchars)
        return last10[0...2] + "-" + last10[3...5] + "-" + last10[6...9]
    }
}
```

then you just do:

```
"1 (208) 754-2323".phoneFormat()
```

and it comes out clean: "208-754-2323"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var number = "(123) 456-789"
let clean:NSString = number.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
        "[(][1-9]+[)] |[-]",
```

Comment: My code is working. But how to remove first 4 chars if I will have number like this "0044 123456789"?

Comment: This code automaticly removes the first 3 numbers with the brackets and the space, and also the "-".